# Cannot accept calendar invitations

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical

I’m an experienced Apple user but I cannot see how to accept a calendar invitation using Calendar on iOS device or on my Mac. In a calendar invite that I received there’s just a question mark next to my name.

In desperation, I logged into iCloud.com with Safari. In the online calendar I scrolled to the bottom of an appointment where there was a “reply” drop down. I selected “Accept” and pressed enter, but all I get is an error dialog: “Calendar has stopped responding.”

I’ve hunted around the web, but can’t find a similar situation.

Comment: When you get an invite you should have a notification and the "Inbox" with a count of invitations and other notifications from calendars that have changed. An Invitation, when tapped on, should give you the opportunity to accept or decline. Does this not happen?